# Solr Sunspot Autocomplete Text Field Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, solr, sunspot

I am using the sunspot_autocomplete gem to implement auto suggest to my search bar. Just need some help creating the text field. I am using rails 3.

Before I installed the gem, my search bar's code looked like this:

```
<%= form_tag dairies_path, :method => :get do %>
<p>
    <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], style:"width:550px; height:30px;", :autofocus => true %><br>
    <%= submit_tag "Search!", :name => nil, class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg", style: "margin-top:20px" %>
</p>
<% end %>
```

The autocomplete gem requires this code for a text field:

```
<%= autosuggest_text_field "dairy", "title", "http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/", "dairy_title"%>
```

My question is do I replace all of the search bar code with that ^ or do I just replace the text_field_tag line? I have either been getting errors, or the entire code shows up on my website. Sorry for the beginner question. Still lots to learn! Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you require the appropriate files in your asset pipeline `app/assets/stylesheets/` and `app/assets/javascripts/` ?

Comment: Could you show us the errors you are getting.

Comment: `<input id="dairy_title" name="dairy[title]" size="30" type="text" /> <script>$('#dairy_title').autosuggest('http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/', 'dairy_title', {});</script>` this shows up on my home page. For some reason I'm not getting an error anymore.

Comment: Not sure if i'm adding the text field to the right place